# Why does declaring the same function both with and without parameters not cause compilation errors?

Tags: c, compiler-warnings, function-declaration, integer-promotion

For the code:

```
int hi(int);
int hi();
int main()
{
    hi(3);
}
```

I don't get any compilation errors (calling `hi()`; without arguments does get a compilation error).

I expected that the compiler would complain that the function has already been declared differently. Any idea why this is the behavior?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can declare the same symbol as many times as you like, and as long as the declarations don't contradict each other, you won't get an error.

The reason that

```
int hi();
```

doesn't contradict

```
int hi(int);
```

is because a declaration without any arguments at all means that you say you really don't know how many arguments there are or what types they are. That doesn't really contradict the first declaration. And because you already declared `hi`, the compiler will simply use that declaration.

---

As noted in a comment, this will change with the C23 standard. It has adopted the semantics from C++ that no explicit arguments means `void`, so

```
int hi();
```

will be equivalent to

```
int hi(void);
```

That of course means that the two declarations *will* be contradicting each other.

Comment: Note that in C23, the two function declarations will contradict each other.  The `int hi();` declaration will be like C++ and equivalent to `int hi(void);`, which will indeed contradict `int hi(int);`.  Until then, this analysis is sound.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Ah, so they adopted the C++ semantics for that? Din't know that. Thanks :)

Answer (score 5):

You may use several compatible function declarations if among them there is no more than one function definition.

In C there is defined the notion of ***compatible types***.

From the C11 Standard (6.2.7 Compatible type and composite type)

> 1 Two types have compatible type if their types are the same.
> Additional rules for determining whether two types are compatible are
> described in 6.7.2 for type specifiers, in 6.7.3 for type qualifiers,
> and in 6.7.6 for declarators.

and (6.7 Declarations)

> 4 All declarations in the same scope that refer to the same object or
> function shall specify compatible types.

and at last (6.7.6.3 Function declarators (including prototypes))

> 15. ... If one type has a parameter type list and the other type
>     is specified by a function declarator that is not part of a function
>     definition and that contains an empty identifier list, the parameter
>     list shall not have an ellipsis terminator and the type of each
>     parameter shall be compatible with the type that results from the
>     application of the default argument promotions.

In the both these function declarations

```
int hi(int);
int hi();
```

the return types are compatible (they are the same). And the parameter of the first function declaration has the type `int`  that corresponds to the  type of the integer promotions.

From the C11 Standard 6.5.2.2 Function calls)

> 6 If the expression that denotes the called function has a type that
> does not include a prototype, the integer promotions are performed on
> each argument, and arguments that have type float are promoted to
> double. These are called the ***default argument promotions***.

If you would write for example

```
int hi(char);
int hi();
```

then there are declared two different functions because the type `char` , the type of the parameter of the first function, does not correspond to a type after default argument promotions.

Another example of declaring two compatible functions and two different functions.

These two declarations declare the same function

```
int hi( double );
int hi();
```

and these two declarations declare different (non-compatible) functions

```
int hi( float );
int hi();
```

In C23 Standard there are done the following changes relative to function declarations

> — mandated function declarations whose parameter list is empty be
> treated the same as a parameter list which only contain a single void;

So according to the C23 Standard these function declarations

```
int hi(int);
int hi();
```

are equivalent to

```
int hi(int);
int hi( void );
```

So they declare two different functions and the compiler should issue a message.